# Office 365 - Individual Outlook Folder Report

Tags: powershell, office365

The following code isn't showing the DisplayName of the user in the results - any ideas?

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics | Where-Object {$_.FolderType 
-eq "Conflicts"} | Select-Object DisplayName,FolderSize,ItemsInFolder
```

Comment: what are you expecting/wanting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow.

The issue your having is that when you do "Get-Mailbox" and pipe it through to "Get-MailboxFolderStatistics" you get the result of "Get-MailboxFolderStatistics" which does not have the property "DisplayName" and this is why it gets returned as blank.

You can use Identity instead which will show the full path of the folder including the display name.

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics | Where-Object {$_.FolderType -eq "Conflicts"} | Select-Object Identity,FolderSize,ItemsInFolder
```

Hope this helps